# Error specifying convolutional base from pre-trained XCeption-architecture with keras in R under Windows

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

Is there something really obvious that I am doing when trying to use the convolutional base from the XCeption architecture pre-trained on ImageNet? Here is my code that produces  the error at the end of the question:

```
require(keras)

conv_base1 <- application_xception(
weights = "imagenet",
include_top = FALSE,
pooling=FALSE,
input_shape = c(300, 300, 3)
)

model51 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
conv_base1 %>%
layer_flatten() %>%
layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

In contrast, the almost identical code below using application_vgg16 works just fine:

```
require(keras)

conv_base2 <- application_vgg16(
weights = "imagenet",
include_top = FALSE,
pooling=FALSE,
input_shape = c(300, 300, 3)
)

model52 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
conv_base2 %>%
layer_flatten() %>%
layer_dense(units = 2048, activation = "relu") %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

I get the following errors (using R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) on Windows 10 x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) using the keras_2.1.5 R package):

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>   ValueError: Variable block1_conv1_bn_1/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in init
>   self._traceback = _extract_stack()
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
>   op_def=op_def)
>
> Detailed traceback:
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 467, in add
>   layer(x)
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 617, in call
>   output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2081, in call
>   output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
>   File "D:\Anaconda3\l

**Further background in case it matters:** I ran into this when trying to replace VGG16 with XCeption in the "Freature extraction with data augementation" subsection of Section 5.3.1 of Chollet and Allaire's most excellent book (everything in "Fast feature extraction without data augmentation" works just fine with both VGG16 and XCeption).

Comment: Are you trying to create "both" xception and vgg? Or are you trying to create xception more than once? Maybe this is just a name conflict. Reset your R, console or whatever you're using to program and create "only one" xception model (and don't try to create a VGG model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the source of this error, but I suspect it's related to using a model inside another model (adding the basemodel into a sequential model).

I suggest trying to use a functional API model. But unfortunately I'm not good with R to understand its notation.

The idea is ([copied from here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/articles/functional_api.html), I hope the syntax is ok. Anyone with better R understanding can fix this code)

First define the xception model normally:

```
conv_base1 <- application_xception(
weights = "imagenet",
include_top = FALSE,
pooling=FALSE,
input_shape = c(300, 300, 3)
)
```

**Try 1:**

Now let's get the output tensor of this model and pass it to further layers

```
#the inputs of the following layers is the output of the exception model     
    #this is where I can't handle with R, these two lines may be wrong
base_inputs <- conv_base1$input
base_outputs <- conv_base1$output

#the base_outputs are the input tensor to further layers
#predictions is the output tensor from those layers
predictions <- base_outputs %>%
    layer_flatten() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid') 

# create and compile model - model starts at base_inputs and ends at predcitions
model <- keras_model(inputs = base_inputs, outputs = predictions)
```

---

**Try 2:**

Alternatively, if defining `base_inputs` and `base_outputs` is not possible the way it was indended in the other code:

```
inputs <- layer_input(shape = c(300,300,3))

# outputs compose input + layers, where conv_base1 should behave like a layer
predictions <- inputs %>%
    conv_base1 %>%
    layer_flatten() %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid') 

# create and compile model
model <- keras_model(inputs = inputs, outputs = predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, this also does not work on my computer. Accidentally, because I first saw your response during my workday, I first tried it on my work computer and as it turns out that both the code that originally caused me problems and what you posted work just fine on my work computer. In contrast, my home computer cannot cope with either version. I tried updating R to a new version and that also did not help. I am thoroughly puzzled.

Comment: Maybe it's the keras version?

Comment: Did you test with both Try 1 and Try 2?

Comment: I tested Try 2 (I also know too little to figure out what I'd have to do with Try 1). I just upgraded my R (to 3.5.0), my keras version in Python from 2.1.4 to 2.1.5 (which matches my work computer) and that did not help. The R tensorflow and keras packages are also the latest. However, it really looks like even what I tried originally should work (since it worked on my work computer, which due to our company IT department has R 3.3.3) and the problem is somehow with the setup I have on my home computer (or R versions after 3.3.3). Not sure whether the error messages give any useful hint.

Comment: I think Try 1 may still be worthy trying, but I can't find any help on the internet on how to get the output tensor of a model with R. In python it's simply `conv_base1.output`.

Comment: Try `base_inputs <- conv_base1$input` and `base_outputs <- conv_base1$output`.

Comment: Mmmh, that seems to have worked. I'll try whether I can train it.

Comment: Actually, that is what I managed to get to work before: reading in the outputs of the convolutional base only.

Comment: Arrg! It looks like I was mistaken about using the latest tensorflow! It really was as simple as upgrading my tensorflow version in Python. I realized that this was it after trying to do the same thing in python and then getting a clearer error message, where googling then lead me to a thread that explained this. With tensorflow 1.5.x the problem goes away. Thank you very much for your help, now every version of the code works (my own original, your try 1 and your try 2).